# My results keep adding up, how do I replace the current results with the new results every time a new choice is made?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

The game is working, however I am trying to replace the old results with new results every time a new choice is made.  The results just keep pilling up until I reload the page.  I've tried if/else statements, tired adding a new function to replace the old results and tried adding a new event listener to replace the old ones. I am very new to this and any advice would be great.  Thanks.
\\

```
const player = {
  currentChoice: null
}

const computer = {
  currentChoice: null
}

const choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

const rock_div = document.getElementById('r');
const paper_div = document.getElementById('p');
const scissors_div = document.getElementById('s');


rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pick(choice[0]);  
})
paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pick(choice[1]);  
  })
scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pick(choice[2]); 
})


function pick(userChoice) {  
  player.currentChoice = userChoice;
  compareChoices();
  console.log(player.currentChoice);
}                     

function computerChooses(){
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length);
  computer.currentChoice = choice[randomIndex];
}

function compareChoices(){
  computerChooses();  
if (computer.currentChoice === player.currentChoice){
  displayResult("It's a tie! Computer and Player choose " + computer.currentChoice);
}else if(computer.currentChoice === choice[0]){
  if(player.currentChoice === choice[1]){
    displayResult("Player Wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and player 
chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }else{
      displayResult("Computer Wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and 
player chose " + player.currentChoice);
     }
  }else if(computer.currentChoice === choice[1]){
    if(player.currentChoice === choice[2]){
      displayResult("Player Wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and 
player chose " + player.currentChoice);
  }else{
  displayResult("Computer Wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and player 
chose " + player.currentChoice);
  }
    }else if(computer.currentChoice === choice[2]){
    if(player.currentChoice === choice[0]){
    displayResult("Player Wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and player 
chose " + player.currentChoice);
  }else{
    displayResult("Computer Wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and 
player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  }
}
function displayResult(winner){
  const result = document.createElement('h3');
  result.innerText = winner;
  document.body.appendChild(result);
}
```

\\

Comment: You could give your h3 an ID, then each time you call displayResult remove the element with that ID prior to adding the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your results are added to the page multiple times is because you're continually inserting `<h3>` tags into the HTML via `document.body.appendChild(result);`.

A simple fix for this in your example would be to remove any existing `h3` tags in your HTML before you attempt to display your result.

```js
function displayResult(winner){
  document.querySelector('h3')?.remove();
  const result = document.createElement('h3');
  result.innerText = winner;
  document.body.appendChild(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function displayResult(winner){

  // Remove the element if it already exists
  var elem = document.getElementById("result-indicator");
  if (elem) {
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  }

  const result = document.createElement('h3');
  result.innerText = winner;
  result.id = 'result-indicator'; // Give it an ID so we can remove it again later
  document.body.appendChild(result);

}
```